# Firebase Storage putFile() queing issue

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

**THE STORY**

I am using Firebase Storage in my app. So far it works as expected and uploads files as I had wanted it to.

I have no problem in uploading a single file.

**THE PROBLEM**

My requirement is not to upload a single file, but multiple files as selected by the user and in the same order as selected.

I need a properly queue the upload tasks one by one, so that only when a particular upload ends (success or failure) the new one can start.

In the current scenario **all the files upload simultaneously**, which is not the behaviour I want.

**POSSIBLE APPROACH**

I don't see any Firebase API to do this. I can do this myself but for this I need the **putFile() call to be async** and not sync.

If that can be done, I can wait for a particular putFile() complete and then queue the next upload and then the next, so on.

Please help me in solving this problem. Whether my approach is okay to attempt or if you have any better way to solve this problem?

Comment: Sounds like you have a pretty good grasp of your problem. Did you try writing any of the code yet? If so, you'll probably get help faster if you show what you've already tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: Did you solve your problem yet ,if yes please post your answer.